# No qualifying bean of type available exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

Im trying to Deserialize a hashmap using jackson. My data structure is

```
public class FilterDto {

    private Map<String, List<String>> sectorFilter;

    public FilterDto() {}

    public Map<String, List<String>> getSectorFilter() {
        return sectorFilter;
    }

    public void setSectorFilter(Map<String, List<String>> sectorFilter) {
        this.sectorFilter = sectorFilter;
    }

}
```

My request body is

```
{
  "sectorFilter": [
    {
      "ab": [
        "abc",
        "cde"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When i tried to deserialize this i got

```
Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>` out of START_ARRAY token
```

So i tried using a custom deserialzer to see whether it would work. I created a custom deerialzer like below

```
public class FilterDeserializer  extends StdDeserializer<Map<String,List<String>>> {


    public FilterDeserializer(StdDeserializer<?> src) {
        super(src);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String,List<String>> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        
    }
}
```

and added it to my dto

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = FilterDeserializer.class)
private Map<String, List<String>> sectorFilter;
```

but now im getting

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer<?>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

any idea how can i get this work ? Thanks

Comment: change your "sectorFilter" in request to object(start and finish with {} not []) or if it is an array you should change "Map<String, List<String>>"  to list of map "List<Map<String, List<String>>>"

Comment: @Dilantha, please consider upvoting and accept the provided answer below so that the question can be "closed" and others benefit from it ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sectorFilter`, as you’ve shown, isn’t a map, it’s an array of JSON objects. Try to deserialize as `List<Map<String, List<String>>>`. Of course, you can also create classes mimicking that structure if you want.